# Using replace method to change password

Tags: vb.net

I am using following code to replace the passwords in my app.config.  It replaces successfully but does not reload config file in the memory so datasets give error of wrong password.
Please help

```
 Dim vrTextFind As String = "Password"
    Dim vrTextReplaceWith As String = "PWD"
    Dim path As String = "D:\VS2008\EncTest\EncTest\bin\Debug\enctest.exe.config"
    Dim readText As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
    TextBox1.Text = readText
    'Find
    Dim idx As Integer = 0
    idx = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(vrTextFind, idx)
    If idx = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show(vrTextFind & " is not in Textbox1")
    Else
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = idx
        TextBox1.SelectionLength = vrTextFind.Length
    End If
    'Replace
    If TextBox1.Text.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(vrTextFind, vrTextReplaceWith)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text & " is not in Textbox3")
    End If
    '''''
    'Write all back
    File.WriteAllText(path, TextBox1.Text)
    'Refreshes the connection string section
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings")
```

Comment: Is the password you are using, is the password of connection string?
Why are you refreshing section connection string?
Does textbox1.text contains connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows application `app.config` is read only once, when the application starts. If you modify it you will need to restart the app.

**Suggestion**

Instead of storing password in `app.config` store it in some other file (like Settings file). Which can be modified and read at runtime. For `Settings` you can read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#settingscs_topic4). And choose `User-Scope` settings.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but what does ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings") mean?  Can this be read again?

Comment: Tried with console app, but it didn't refresh the connection string. But +1 for ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using File.WriteallText use the following code to write to app.config:

```
config.AppSettings.Settings.Item("ConnectionString").Value = TextBox1.Text
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("AppSettings")
```

Then again load the connection string value from app.config.

```
Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration
Dim fileMap As New ExeConfigurationFileMap()

fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "Path of app.config"
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

'   Sets values to config file.
If config.HasFile() Then

    strConnString = config.AppSettings.Settings.Item("ConnectionString").Value

End If
```

Comment: How do I reload the connection string value?   ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("AppSettings") does it?

Comment: See my updated answer.
Just get the values from app.config & put it in a variable and use it.